# How to simplify the variance of $\sqrt{1+\frac{4\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}{n}}$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be $n \ $ i.i.d random variables such that $X_i \sim N(\theta,\theta)$ where $\theta > 0$.

Now, I am trying to simplify $$\text{var}\bigg(\sqrt{1+\frac{4\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}{n}}\bigg).$$ I got this expression in some calculation that I am doing.

Only, the square root is creating problems. I can't get my head around this. Please help.

Thanks!

**EDIT :** I have to show that $$\text{var}\bigg(\sqrt{1+\frac{4\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}{n}}\bigg) \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty.$

**EDIT 2 :** MLE of $\theta$ is $$\hat{\theta}_{MLE} = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+\frac{4\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}{n}}}{2}$$.

I am trying to prove the consistency of $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know your purpose but surely you can approximate

$$\mathbb{V}\Bigg[\sqrt{1+4\overline{X}_n}\Bigg]$$

using Delta Method.

---

EDIT: your estimator is

$$T=\sqrt{1+4\frac{\Sigma_i X_i^2}{n}}$$

After usual calculations,

$$\hat{\theta}_{ML}=\frac{T-1}{2}$$

The asymptotic distribution of MLE is known...easy solved problem (as an approximation, obviously)

---

EDIT: at the end, the problem was different.

Reading the complete original text

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. random variables with ditribution $N(\theta;\theta)$ for some unknown $\theta>0$. Compute the MLE of $\theta$ and show it is Consistent

After calculating $\hat{\theta}_{ML}$ that you did correctly let's go back to the Score that is

$$l^*(\theta)=-\frac{n}{2\theta}-\frac{n}{2}+\frac{\Sigma_i X_i^2}{2\theta^2}$$

The derivative of the score is

$$l^{**}(\theta)=\frac{n}{2\theta^2}-\frac{\Sigma_i X_i^2}{\theta^3}$$

Thus the Fischer information is

$$I_n(\theta)=-\mathbb{E}[l^{**}(\theta)]=-\frac{n}{2\theta^2}+\frac{(\theta+\theta^2)n}{\theta^3}=\frac{(1+2\theta)n}{2\theta^2}$$

Concluding:

The asymptotic distribution is the following

$$\hat{\theta}_{ML}\dot{\sim} N\Bigg[\theta;\frac{2\theta^2}{(1+2\theta)n}\Bigg]$$

This means that

$$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}_{ML}]=\theta$$

and

$$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\mathbb{V}[\hat{\theta}_{ML}]=0$$

Which is a necessary and sufficient condition for consistency

Comment: Sorry, it is $X_i^2$ not $X_i$. I did a mistake and I edited the question and added some more details.

Comment: @uuuuuuuuuu : better it is! which is ML estimator for $\theta$? the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\theta}_{ML}$ is known....your estimator is function of MLE thus...

Comment: I added some more details.

Comment: @uuuuuuuuuu : me too...Consistency is a property of MLE

Comment: So, you mean MLE is always consistent? Then why the question is asking me to prove the consistency?

Comment: See problem no 2 here - https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-650-statistics-for-applications-fall-2016/assignments/MIT18_650F16_PSet3.pdf

Comment: @uuuuuuuuuu the question is "show it is consistent". Yes it is as any MLE is. You can easy show the property with the asymptotic distribution, as I suggested you

Comment: @uuuuuuuuuu : I edited my answer with a complete solution of the problem. For the future it is better that you post the complete text of the exercise, in order to avoid misunderstandings. If my answer has been useful for you, you can mark it as accepted